# How to code a tool, that checks a specific website and sends an email if down?

Tags: php

I want to code a tool, that checks a specific url a few times a day and automatically sends an email, if the website is not available (404). I want to use this for snapping expired domains.

Can anyone provide some recources on that? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 0):

- To schedule a PHP file to run a certain times of the day check out [Cron Jobs](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/)
- To connect to a third party website using PHP check out [Curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- To send out an email via PHP, check out the inbuilt `mail()` function [PHP mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

The above should be ample to get you going.